# Can Durandaljs work with angularjs directives?

Tags: angularjs, durandal

I am not a web developer and have been tasked to look at web frameworks (with foucs on SPA in particular). Our emphasis is largely business applications.

Having followed some of the excellent Rob Eisenberg has done with Caliburn, Durandaljs is where I am leaning towards. However, the company I work for has some UI 'components' written with AngularJs.

My question is can I use these components in Durandaljs views?

Comment: They kinda do the same thing and are competing frameworks.  I would just pick one.

Comment: If we don't go with angulars routing etc can we not just use the components?

Comment: I am concerned about the effort that has been put into creating angularjs components. Can we not reuse that in Durandaljs?

Comment: Seems a lot of overhead to load in two data-binding and dependency-injection frameworks just to reuse some components. It's all trade-offs but what you save in development time you might lose in troubleshooting and overhead with a poorly performing app that has two frameworks doing the same thing.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy for your reply, as I am still researching on the pros and cons of each framework, I was hoping I could pull in parts of Angularjs that I needed but having read more on components, most have injected services so that wont work.